# Google Sheets: Chart counting combinations

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, count, pivot, google-query-language

In the following Google spreadsheet

| Description | No. of participants | Severity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Problem 1 | 2 | Minor |
| Problem 2 | 2 | Major |
| Problem 3 | 1 | Minor |
| Problem 4 | 1 | Minor |
| Problem 5 | 2 | Major |

I would like to create a chart that has the No. of participants as x-axis, the Severity as y-axis and counts the number of combinations.

The example above would look like this:

|  | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Minor | 2 | 1 |
| Major | 0 | 2 |

Also, I would like to list all items in the column description according to their combination of No. of participants and severity like this:

|  | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Minor | Problem 3 | Problem 1 |
| Minor | Problem 4 |  |
| Major |  | Problem 2 |
| Major |  | Problem 5 |

How can I get this chart extracted from the table in Google Sheets?

Thanks to @player0 the first part is answered. He also suggested something for the second part that does not quite work out yet:

To get the basic table:

```
=QUERY(A2:C6; "select C, max(A) where A is not null group by C pivot B order by C desc")
```

To display several items in one cell:

```
=MAP(B2:B6; C2:C6; LAMBDA(x; y; TEXTJOIN(CONCATENATE(CHAR(10);CHAR(10)); 1; FILTER(A2:A6; B2:B6=x; C2:C6=y))))
```

Unfortunately, combining both does not work out:

```
=QUERY((MAP(B2:B6; C2:C6; LAMBDA(x; y; TEXTJOIN(CONCATENATE(CHAR(10);CHAR(10)); 1; FILTER(A2:A6; B2:B6=x; C2:C6=y)))); B2:C6); "select C,max(A) where A is not null group by C pivot B order by C desc")
```

Nor does this one work:

```
=QUERY((MAP(B2:B6; C2:C6; LAMBDA(x; y; TEXTJOIN(CONCATENATE(CHAR(10);CHAR(10)); 1; FILTER(A2:A6; B2:B6=x; C2:C6=y)))); B2:C6); "select Col1,max(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col3 pivot Col2 order by Col3 desc")
```

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=QUERY(A2:C; "select C,count(A) where A is not null group by C pivot B order by C desc")
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=QUERY({MAP(B2:B, C2:C, LAMBDA(x, y, TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, FILTER(A2:A, B2:B=x, C2:C=y)))), B2:C}, 
 "select Col3,max(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col3 pivot Col2 order by Col3 desc")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this great solution. Admittedly, I haven't understood what you did there to adapt it to the case where, instead of the counted combinations, the description texts, i. e. "Problem 1" etc. should be displayed in the same table. I tried to consult: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en
Would you be willing to elaborate on this?

Comment: @Yahalnaut not sure I can elaborate without knowing what exactly you want. if you want different output share a copy /sample of your sheet with example of desired result or open a new question

Comment: Apparently it is hard to layout a table in the comments. In your anser the cells F3:G4 should contain the Problem string. For example, F3 would contain "Problem 3" and "Problem 4". Really sorry for the clumsy description.

Comment: @Yahalnaut answer updated